# Error while implementing Autoform in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I received the following error while implementing the tested code of [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/autoform-demo). The clone runs fine. I have installed the package: aldeed. Where is the mistake?

```
Error: Invalid definition for firstName field.
    W20150407-15:40:16.988(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/aldeed:simple-schema/simple-schema.js:62:1
    W20150407-15:40:16.988(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
    W20150407-15:40:16.988(5.5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].SimpleSchema (packages/aldeed:simple-schema/simple-schema.js:59:1)
    W20150407-15:40:16.988(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/common/1_schemas.js:5:18
    W20150407-15:40:16.988(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/common/1_schemas.js:123:3
    W20150407-15:40:16.988(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/garima.wadhera/autoform/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
    W20150407-15:40:16.989(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
    W20150407-15:40:16.989(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.2.2ai5r5++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    W20150407-15:40:16.989(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/garima.wadhera/autoform/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
```

Comment: Post your code. There's a problem with how you defined the schema

Comment: https://github.com/aldeed/autoform-demo/blob/master/common/1_schemas.js

Comment: I have not made changes to this code

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're running. You said the close works fine. Also, there's no package called aldeed. He's a package author

Comment: I created a meteor project and added certain folders from autoform demo project: common, server and some folders of client/views

Comment: Like you  said, the close works, so it's difficult to guess where the problem. Firstname in the demo code had a valid definition. Try running your code with Autoform.debug =true; that might give you more info.

Comment: package is aldeed:autoform